# Socket Stuck in CLOSE_WAIT

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I am getting sockets stuck in close_wait when two of my daemons speak to each other. After having read different questions and blog entries on the subject, I have verified that I am closing the socket from both sides (originator and receiver).

The model goes as follows:

Sender:
establish connection, send data, wait for confirmation, close connection

Receiver:
receive connection, read data, send confirmation, close connection

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Note: I am using close() to close the connections right now. I have tried using shutdown as well and it hasn't changed things. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Shortly after closing the socket, the receiving daemon forks. I have tried passing the file descriptor to the function that forks and explicitly closing it again in the child process, but this did not fix my problem. Is there any other way that forking could affect this process? Note that the sending daemon does not fork.

Comment: Do you mean `TIME_WAIT` state?

Comment: What do you mean "stuck"? The whole point is for it to take a few minutes for them to recycle.  Use SO_REUSEADDR via `setsockopt` if you want to avoid the wait.

Comment: @Duck - by stuck I mean that I see other sockets open and close (no longer appear in netstat's output) rapidly, but one set of connections open and go to the CLOSE_WAIT state indefinitely. I have watched it for 5 minutes or so and they don't seem to ever close. They now have persisted for 10 minutes. I don't think they ever go away.

Comment: @sarnold - no, I mean CLOSE_WAIT

Comment: @dbeer: CLOSE_WAIT means that you haven't `close()`d

Comment: do you close the right socket?

Comment: Yes, I do close the right socket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking in wireshark, I saw that the final FIN_ACK said:

"[TCP ACKed lost segment] [TCP previous segment lost] ..."

It turns out that my problem was caused by having both daemons running on the same box (something we had added for testing). After trying again on multiple boxes, we no longer get this problem.

Answer (score 0):

when you have an application which has opened a socket and after doing some send receive it accepts a FIN from its peer, from that states onwards it goes to CLOSE_WAIT state. It can remain in that state forever until you explicitly call close(). Hope you are actually passing the right FD in close().

Comment: As stated in my question, I explicitly call close(). I don't believe its possible that my file descriptor could be wrong. See my comment on the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my (short) experience, it's very possible that you're closing the wrong fd, or even not reaching the "close" statement at all. I stumbled upon the later one and the first clue was that my application became a zombie instead of closing (specifically a simple printf right before the close statement made it all go to hell).

Might be worth your time to check the task manager/jobs/system monitor/< some process view name relevant to your OS>.

Comment: I am talking about two daemons. They don't stop running, so I don't think they can become zombies. As far as the wrong file descriptor, I can't see how that would be possible. The code goes: fd = open_socket(); send_info(fd, info); read_reply(fd, &ret); close(fd); I don't see any way it could have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually these are quite common problems witnessed in multi-threaded server applications
There are two things you could do to resolve this problem:

1. Use FD_CLOSEXEC on the sockets.
2. Use setsockopt and set tcp_keepalive on the sockets.

The code for implementation of both of the above solutions can be a little different on *NIX and Microsoft. The difference is only due to semantic differences.

I would recommend implementing both of the above measures.

However if you cannot modify the code then you could use
[libkeepalive](http://libkeepalive.sourceforge.net/)